# Map an asp URL to an aspx Http[Handler/Module]

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, httphandler, httpmodule

We are rewriting an old site for a client, from **Classic ASP** to **ASP.NET 4**. The new site will be living at the same root URL as the old one once it is pushed live.

One stipulation though is this... the old site used to use a page such as `article.asp?articleid=###` to load content. The new site will be using something similar, but making use of ASP.NET Routing such as `~/articles/o/###` (the 'o' is for 'old id').

I need to be able to catch requests to the old `article.asp` page and rewrite the url to the new `article.aspx` url.

My original thought was to handle this in the `Application_BeginRequest`. I remapped the .ASP extension to be handled by the same handler dll as .ASPX pages, and then added the following code to my `Application_BeginRequest` in my `global.asax`:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctx = HttpContext.Current, url = ctx.Request.RawUrl
    If Regex.IsMatch(url, "/article\.asp\?articleid=\d+") Then
        Dim oldid = Regex.Match(url, "(?:articleid=)(\d+)").Groups(1).Value
        Server.Transfer("~/articles/o/" & oldid)
    End If
End Sub
```

This did not work though. As this is right now, I need to have an actual `article.asp` in the path or else I get a **404** error (and even then it doesn't actually do anything, and just displays a blank page). This would work fine (assuming redirect code in the ASP page worked), except that they had 500 copies of `article.asp` each in their own sub-directory (breaking the whole point of a CMS model). They want to preserve the old urls in case someone clicks an old one from an email or bookmark.

I need to be able to map this file name to the new path, irregardless of the sub-directory it was in, as per the logic in my `Application_BeginRequest` above. What would be the proper way to do this? As `global.asax` isn't working, I'm assuming I need to either write an `HttpHandler` or `HttpModule` class, but I'm not sure which is the right way to go.

Running IIS on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Thanks!

Comment: which webserver? to handle .asp pages within asp.net is a configuration issue of your webserver, not a problem with asp.net.

Comment: Added info on the server... sorry about that. I do have IIS configed to handle the ASP page with the ASPX handler, but I need to figure out how and where to catch the request properly so I can rewrite it to the new CMS model.

Comment: so your above code is executing for every request, but you need help to tweak your regular expression to match requests to asp-files in any arbitrary subfolder?

Comment: AH! STUPID! Spent all this time researching HttpHandlers and HttpModules and yeah, forgot to escape the special chars in my RegEx. Though that wasn't ultimately the answer, but definitely a bug... thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my above code in the `Application_BeginRequest` method of `global.asax` actually WAS a right place. The problem was one more missing setting in IIS. In the dialog where you remap `.ASP` to the `ASP.NET` handler, you also need to make sure to turn off the option for **Verify that file exists**. This completed the procedure, and my old pages now map to the corresponding new pages.